# NullPointerExcpetion

Tags: java

Olá amigos do stackoverflow, estou terminando a minha calculadora e estou com problemas de nullpointer, sou novo em java e não sei bem como mudar a lógica para resolver o problema, lá vai o código que estou tendo problemas

```
 public Double calcular() throws Exception 
{
int tamanhoFila = this.expressao.trim().length();
Fila fila = new Fila<>(tamanhoFila);
Pilha pilha = new Pilha<>(tamanhoFila);
String regex = "[0-9]+";
    String[] elementos = quebraExressao(this.expressao.trim());

    for (String token : elementos)
{
        if (!token.equals(""))
        {
    if (token.matches(regex))   // se for numero
    {
                fila.emfila(token);
    }
    else    // se for operador
    {
                if (pilha.isVazia())
                {
        pilha.insere(token);
                }
                else 
                {
        String ultimoOperador = pilha.getUltimoElemento().toString();

        if (Tabela.devoDesempilhar(ultimoOperador.charAt(0), token.charAt(0)))
        {
                        if (token.equals(")"))
                        {
            while(!pilha.getUltimoElemento().equals("("))
            {
                                fila.emfila(pilha.retira());
            }
                                pilha.retira(); // para retirar o (
                        }
                        else 
                        {
            while(Tabela.devoDesempilhar(ultimoOperador.charAt(0), token.charAt(0)))
            {
                                fila.emfila(pilha.retira());
                                if (pilha.isVazia())
                                {
                pilha.insere(token);
                break;
                                }
                                else 
                ultimoOperador = pilha.getUltimoElemento().toString();
            }
                        }
        }
        else 
        {
                        pilha.insere(token);
        }
                }

    }
        }
}
```

mais precisamente nessa linha

```
for (String token : elementos)
```

como mudar a logica de modo que resolva o problema do Null Pointer?

A pedido aqui está o metodo QuebraEXPRESSAO:

```
private static String[] quebraExressao(String expressao)
{
    expressao = expressao.replaceAll(" ", "").replaceAll("", " ");
            String regex = "[0-9]";
            String[] elementos = expressao.split(" ");
            String[] elementos_retorno = new String[elementos.length];
            int j = 0;

            for (int i =0; i < elementos.length; i++)
            {
                if (elementos[i].matches(regex))
                {
                    if (i+1 < elementos.length)
                    {      
                      if (elementos[i+1].matches(regex))
                       {
                        elementos_retorno[j] = elementos[i] + elementos[i+1];
                        i++;
                       }
                        else 
                        {
                         elementos_retorno[j] = elementos[i];
                        }
                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                    elementos_retorno[j] = elementos[i];
                }

                j++;
            }

    return elementos_retorno;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Boa noite,

Cara provavelmente o erro pode está nessa linha aqui:

```
String[] elementos = quebraExressao(this.expressao.trim());
```

Se o erro está no for, o elementos deve ser null, verifique o método e o parametro novamente da linha acima que deve está retornando null.

Answer (score 0):

O problema que você está tendo é por que a sua função:

```
quebraExressao()
```

Por algum motivo (que não deu para ver , por que a função nao está no codigo) está retornando null.

Na hora de rodar as instruções do foreach ela tenta arrancar um elemento da lista elementos e atribui-lo a variavel token que você especificou, e sendo o array null ele não consegue chamar essas funções internas de pop do array e ae joga a exceção.

Uma solução para isso seria você na função de quebraExpressao() colocar um retorno "default" , um Array vazio, para que mesmo em caso da sua logica retornar nulo, você teria uma variavel elementos inicializada.

```
 private String[] quebraExpressao() {
         String[] retorno = new String[]{};
         ....
         logica em que vc atribui o retorno esperado a variavel retorno
         e assim sobreescrevendo o "default" array vazio, caso ela não seja null
         ....
         return retorno;
 }
```

Comment: Se eu colocar o código pode dar uma visualizada melhor?

Comment: Sim , coloca a quebraExpressao

Comment: Vou editar o post

Comment: Adicionei o método

Comment: Aquele .replaceAll é só para tirar os espaços em branco ? Se for o primeiro replaceAll já faz isso, nao precisaria do segundo

Comment: Infelizmente não fui eu que fiz essa parte , mas me foi me dito que não é apenas para isso =/

Comment: Bom , como não sei se vocês realmente precisam do segundo replaceAll, ao meu ver quando o codigo chega naquele split, ele não faria o split , por que ele não acharia o espaço em branco que você pede para ele usar como delimitador. Nesse caso , eu acho que você deveria debugar essa função , colocaria um breakpoint no comeco da função e iria vendo os valores atribuidos as variaveis para ver se estão dentro do esperado. O problema de vocês está na lógica da função , o restante é debuggar e achar o erro.